# Django error's when I try to view webpage source

Tags: python, html, django, post, hidden-field

I'm using Django to create a web app for a class. The snippet of HTML below is what I think might be causing my problem.

```
<form action="press" method="POST">
<table>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
      {% if output %}
        <input id="output" name="output" type="text" value="{{output}}" readonly>
      {% else %}
        <input id="output_hidden" name="output" type="text" value="0" readonly>
      {% endif %}
      <input type="hidden" name="buttVal" value="{{buttVal}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="currVal" value="{{currVal}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="prevVal" value="{{prevVal}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="math" value="{{math}}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      </td>
```

I'm using hidden fields to store values to keep the session stateless (point of the assignment). I'm trying to debug my hidden fields, however, after I start my app and trigger the first if statement below, I'm no longer able to view the webpage source (by right clicking in the webpage and clicking on "view source"). When I attempt this, it first says "Document Expired" but it allows me to try the request again. When I try it again, the html below shows up as source.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <title>MultiValueDictKeyError at /press</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; }
    h2 { margin-bottom:.8em; }
    h2 span { font-size:80%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    h3 { margin:1em 0 .5em 0; }
    h4 { margin:0 0 .5em 0; font-weight: normal; }
    code, pre { font-size: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; }
    table { border:1px solid #ccc; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; background:white; }
    tbody td, tbody th { vertical-align:top; padding:2px 3px; }
    thead th { padding:1px 6px 1px 3px; background:#fefefe; text-align:left; font-weight:normal; font-size:11px; border:1px solid #ddd; }
    tbody th { width:12em; text-align:right; color:#666; padding-right:.5em; }
    table.vars { margin:5px 0 2px 40px; }
    table.vars td, table.req td { font-family:monospace; }
    table td.code { width:100%; }
    table td.code pre { overflow:hidden; }
    table.source th { color:#666; }
    table.source td { font-family:monospace; white-space:pre; border-bottom:1px solid #eee; }
    ul.traceback { list-style-type:none; color: #222; }
    ul.traceback li.frame { padding-bottom:1em; color:#666; }
    ul.traceback li.user { background-color:#e0e0e0; color:#000 }
    div.context { padding:10px 0; overflow:hidden; }
    div.context ol { padding-left:30px; margin:0 10px; list-style-position: inside; }
    div.context ol li { font-family:monospace; white-space:pre; color:#777; cursor:pointer; }
    div.context ol li pre { display:inline; }
    div.context ol.context-line li { color:#505050; background-color:#dfdfdf; }
    div.context ol.context-line li span { position:absolute; right:32px; }
    .user div.context ol.context-line li { background-color:#bbb; color:#000; }
    .user div.context ol li { color:#666; }
    div.commands { margin-left: 40px; }
    div.commands a { color:#555; text-decoration:none; }
    .user div.commands a { color: black; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #summary h2 { font-weight: normal; color: #666; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; }
    #template, #template-not-exist { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #template-not-exist ul { margin: 0 0 0 20px; }
    #unicode-hint { background:#eee; }
    #traceback { background:#eee; }
    #requestinfo { background:#f6f6f6; padding-left:120px; }
    #summary table { border:none; background:transparent; }
    #requestinfo h2, #requestinfo h3 { position:relative; margin-left:-100px; }
    #requestinfo h3 { margin-bottom:-1em; }
    .error { background: #ffc; }
    .specific { color:#cc3300; font-weight:bold; }
    h2 span.commands { font-size:.7em;}
    span.commands a:link {color:#5E5694;}
    pre.exception_value { font-family: sans-serif; color: #666; font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px 0 10px 0; }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<!--
    function getElementsByClassName(oElm, strTagName, strClassName){
        // Written by Jonathan Snook, http://www.snook.ca/jon; Add-ons by Robert Nyman, http://www.robertnyman.com
        var arrElements = (strTagName == "*" && document.all)? document.all :
        oElm.getElementsByTagName(strTagName);
        var arrReturnElements = new Array();
        strClassName = strClassName.replace(/\-/g, "\-");
        var oRegExp = new RegExp("(^|\s)" + strClassName + "(\s|$)");
        var oElement;
        for(var i=0; i<arrElements.length; i++){
            oElement = arrElements[i];
            if(oRegExp.test(oElement.className)){
                arrReturnElements.push(oElement);
            }
        }
        return (arrReturnElements)
    }
    function hideAll(elems) {
      for (var e = 0; e < elems.length; e++) {
        elems[e].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
      hideAll(getElementsByClassName(document, 'table', 'vars'));
      hideAll(getElementsByClassName(document, 'ol', 'pre-context'));
      hideAll(getElementsByClassName(document, 'ol', 'post-context'));
      hideAll(getElementsByClassName(document, 'div', 'pastebin'));
    }
    function toggle() {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var e = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
        if (e) {
          e.style.display = e.style.display == 'none' ? 'block': 'none';
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
    function varToggle(link, id) {
      toggle('v' + id);
      var s = link.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
      var uarr = String.fromCharCode(0x25b6);
      var darr = String.fromCharCode(0x25bc);
      s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML == uarr ? darr : uarr;
      return false;
    }
function switchPastebinFriendly(link) {
  s1 = "Switch to copy-and-paste view";
  s2 = "Switch back to interactive view";
  link.innerHTML = link.innerHTML == s1 ? s2: s1;
  toggle('browserTraceback', 'pastebinTraceback');
  return false;
}
//-->
```

Outside of this, I'm not really sure what's going on. I tried googling the problem, but my lack of understanding of this situation kept me from finding anything useful. Hopefully someone can point out something that I'm not doing correctly.

-- EDIT --
Here's my views.py file.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your views here.
def home_page(request):
    index = 'calculator/calculator.html'
    return render(request,index,{})

def press(request):
    context = {}
    operators = ['plus','minus','divide','multiply']
    index = 'calculator/calculator.html'

    ## Discerns from a number and an operator press
    if 'val' in request.POST and is_int(request.POST['val']):
        if request.POST['output'] == '0':
            context['output'] = request.POST['val']
            context['buttVal'] = request.POST['val']
            context['currVal'] = request.POST['val']
        elif request.POST['currVal'] == '0':
            context['output'] = request.POST['val']
            context['buttVal'] = request.POST['val']
            context['currVal'] = request.POST['val']
        else:
            newOutput = request.POST['output'] + request.POST['val']
            context['buttVal'] = request.POST['val']
            context['currVal'] = newOutput
            context['output'] = newOutput

        context['math'] = request.POST['math']
        context['prevVal'] = request.POST['prevVal']

    elif request.POST['val'] == 'clear':
        context['output'] = 0
        context['buttVal'] = 0
        context['currVal'] = 0
        context['prevVal'] = 0
        context['math'] = ''
    elif request.POST['val'] in operators:
        print request.POST
        if request.POST['math'] != '':
            print "poop"
            if request.POST['math'] == 'plus':
                result = int(request.POST['currVal']) + int(request.POST['prevVal'])
                context['prevVal'] = result
                context['output'] = result
            if request.POST['math'] == 'minus':
                result = int(request.POST['currVal']) - int(request.POST['prevVal'])
                context['prevVal'] = result
                context['output'] = result
            if request.POST['math'] == 'multiply':
                result = int(request.POST['currVal']) * int(request.POST['prevVal'])
                context['prevVal'] = result
                context['output'] = result
            if request.POST['math'] == 'divide':
                result = int(request.POST['currVal']) / int(request.POST['prevVal'])
                context['prevVal'] = result
                context['output'] = result
            if request.POST['val'] == 'equal':
                pass
        else:
            context['prevVal'] = request.POST['currVal']
            #context['math'] = request.POST['val']
            context['output'] = request.POST['output']
        context['math'] = request.POST['val']
        context['buttVal'] = request.POST['buttVal']
        context['currVal'] = 0
    else:
        context['output'] = request.POST['output']
        context['buttVal'] = request.POST['buttVal']
        context['math'] = request.POST['math']
        context['prevVal'] = request.POST['prevVal']

     ## Submits POST
    return render(request, index, context)

## Helper functions
def is_int(string):
    try: 
        int(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: The error is somewhere in the python code. Show the  source of the view, please.  Also the last section of the stack trace in the browser should point to actual line, where the error occurs.

Comment: @catavaran, so my web app functions without producing any errors. There are no traditional django errors (pointing to a line) generated when I interact with it. This is part of what's confusing me. The only reason I can tell something is wrong is when I try to manually look at the source code for the webpage. What is the source of the view you're referring to? Is is the webpage source code or maybe the views.py code? If it is the source code then it is the second large code snippet above. I didn't copy the whole thing since it is pretty large.

Comment: The html code from the first snippet can't produce `KeyError`.  So error is in the `views.py` or in the code which is called from `views.py`. You have to show the code of the view function which is mapped to this url.

Comment: No problem, I wanted to make sure that's what you wanted to see before I added. It's ugly, just a disclaimer upfront.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to access to a parameters that are not exist in the `request.POST`.  For example:

```
elif request.POST['val'] == 'clear':
    ...
elif request.POST['val'] in operators:
    ...
else:
    context['output'] = request.POST['output']
    context['buttVal'] = request.POST['buttVal']
    context['math'] = request.POST['math']
    context['prevVal'] = request.POST['prevVal']
```

You didn't check if `val`, `output`, `buttVal`, `prevVal` and `math` are in the `request.POST`.

To safely get values from the `request.POST` use the `get()` method:

```
request.POST.get('val')
```

This expression will return the `val` parameter of the `request.POST` or `None` if such parameter doesn't exist.

Add the `print request.POST` and the very beginning of the `press()` view to see the content of the POST data in the "view source" request.

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because when you view source of a page in a browser, another request is made; but its a GET request.

Thus, your POST dictionary doesn't have those keys, resulting in the exception.

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use forms.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    output = forms.TextField()
    # .. your other fields here

def press(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # do stuff
        return redirect('/home')
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

You can read more about forms (including, how to hide fields and pass initial values) at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/).